# tarring file doesn't tell me why its failing

Tags: jenkins, tar

I'm using the following code to tar files in /var/lib/jenkins

```
tar -czvf $BACKUP_TARBALL_FILE --dereference --exclude "jobs/**/branches" --exclude="builds" --exclude="workspace" --exclude="logs" --exclude=".npm" --exclude="package.json" --exclude="backups" --exclude="thinBackup" --ignore-failed-read /var/lib/jenkins
```

Unfortunately, it fails, but doesn't tell me why. Does anyone know how I can enable error reporting on tar files?

Comment: Are you running as the administrator? Since the folder you're trying to tar is `/var/lib`, you'd need to run tar as an admin user. Also, you can try adding `2>&1` to redirect all `stderr` output to `stdout`

Comment: how do I add 2>&1 to the command?

Comment: `tar -czvf $BACKUP_TARBALL_FILE --dereference --exclude "jobs/**/branches" --exclude="builds" --exclude="workspace" --exclude="logs" --exclude=".npm" --exclude="package.json" --exclude="backups" --exclude="thinBackup" --ignore-failed-read /var/lib/jenkins 2>&1`

Comment: Also, you have `--ignore-failed-read` enabled, so it would ignore all read errors, which I assume is what you want.